# union not working empty results

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I tried using inner join and union not working

```
sql="SELECT * FROM " +
        "(SELECT order_id, order_date, order_status, order_value, order_sapId, order_from, order_clientAcct, order_error, order_visitId, order_cancelled, distributor_name " +
        " FROM `orders` " +
        " JOIN visits  on  visit_id = order_visitId  " +
        " JOIN Name ON user_id = visit_userId  " +
        " JOIN distributor ON distributor_id = visit_outlet_id  " +
        " WHERE order_from = 'CSFA' AND user_id = '"+ App.getUserData("user_id")+"' " +
        ")" +
        " JOIN " +
        "(SELECT   order_id, order_date, order_status, order_value, order_sapId, order_from, order_clientAcct, order_error, order_visitId, order_cancelled,  distributor_name " +
        " FROM `orders` " +
        " JOIN distributor ON order_clientAcct = distributor_accountName " +
        " JOIN user ON salesEmpNo = user_sapId " +
        " WHERE order_from = 'u' AND user_id = '"+ App.getUserData("user_id")+"' " +
        ") " +
        "" +
        "ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 100" +
        "";
```

I need a way to join the two results
1. tried inner join
2.tried union

> E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "(": syntax error
>   11-24 19:53:01.017 13531-13531/E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                         Process: , PID: 13531
>                                                                         android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM (SELECT order_id, order_date, order_status, order_value, order_sapId, order_from, order_clientAcct, order_error, order_visitId, order_cancelled, distributor_name  FROM `orders`  JOIN visits  on  visit_id = order_visitId   JOIN Name ON user_id = visit_userId   JOIN distributor ON distributor_id = visit_outlet_id   WHERE order_from = 'CSFA' AND user_id = '75' ) UNION (SELECT   order_id, order_date, order_status, order_value, order_sapId, order_from, order_clientAcct, order_error, order_visitId, order_cancelled,  distributor_name  FROM `orders`  JOIN distributor ON order_clientAcct = distributor_accountName  JOIN user ON salesEmpNo = user_sapId  WHERE order_from = 'u' AND user_id = '75' ) ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 100

That is the error log

Comment: "not working" care to elaborate? Error messages?

Comment: its sqlite checked for syntax near ( but union come before that

Comment: JOIN and UNION do *entirely different* things. You cannot simply stuff random SQL keywords into your query and expect it to work. And you completely omitted a description of your goal, how your query is supposed to achieve it, sample data, and the desired result.

Comment: as a best practice, you should look into parameterizing your queries.  Doing inline variables like you are may work okay for this instance (as it appears to be coming from what's presumably a database record with an int type) but it's often very unsafe to do this, and can leave your code open to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

after days of research finally got an answer .Used LEFT JOIN and OR to get data from table only where they match.

```
sql="" +
        "SELECT DISTINCT order_id, order_date, order_status, order_value, order_sapId, order_from, order_clientAcct, order_error, order_visitId, order_cancelled, distributor_name " +
        " FROM `orders` " +
        " LEFT JOIN visits,user,distributor  ON  (visit_id = order_visitId AND user_id = visit_userId AND  distributor_id = visit_outlet_id AND order_from = 'CSFA' AND user_id = '"+ App.getUserData("user_id")+"') OR " +
        " " +
        " ( order_clientAcct = distributor_accountName AND salesEmpNo = user_sapId AND order_from = 'SAP' AND user_id = '"+ App.getUserData("user_id")+"' )" +
        " " +
        "ORDER BY order_id DESC LIMIT 100" +
        "";
```